# Adding output of by() to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have the following df:

```
            cat1             cat2                         cat3 rnumb rstar NA    cat4 cat5
1           Appliances Small Appliances                 Coffee Maker  <NA>  <NA> NA    <NA>   NA
8      Health & Beauty           Beauty                   Hair Care   <NA>  <NA> NA Shampoo   NA
9  Holiday Gift Centre       Gift Ideas         Gifts for the Family  <NA>  <NA> NA    <NA>   NA
22     Health & Beauty    Personal Care                      Shaving  <NA>  <NA> NA  Razors   NA
23     Health & Beauty    Personal Care Deodorants & Antiperspirants  <NA>  <NA> NA    <NA>   NA
25     Health & Beauty    Personal Care                Feminine Care  <NA>  <NA> NA    <NA>   NA
```

I have the count of unique cat2 and cat3 for each cat1 using by()

tot.cat2 <- by(x1, x1$cat1, function(x) length(unique(x$cat2)))

```
pur.new$cat1: Apparel
[1] 9
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pur.new$cat1: Appliances
[1] 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pur.new$cat1: Automotive
[1] 7
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pur.new$cat1: Baby
[1] 13
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pur.new$cat1: Electronics
[1] 16
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
pur.new$cat1: Furniture 
[1] 9
```

How do I append these values to the first dataframe? Ideally, in x1 for every row that has Appliances,i want another column that has the number 3,the number of unique cat2 in Appliances.

Comment: You could use `aggregate` i.e. `aggregate(cat2~cat1, x1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: @akrun `x$tot.cat2 <- aggregate(cat2~cat1, x1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`

gives me an error `replacement has 18 rows, data has 25732`

Comment: The `aggregate` output is a data.frame.  You are trying to assign a data.frame to a column.  Just do `x2 <- aggregate(cat2~cat1, x1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`